# I cannot see a shared network folder over IPSEC VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

At first as a proof of concept I had set up a VPN with softether, and I was able to see the folders and easily access them with the program I am trying to use.  However, now I have two Tl-R600VPN routers successfully connect with a IPSEC site to site tunnel.  I can correctly ping the computer that is sharing the folders, and if I type the ip address in the windows explorer I can access it, but it doesn't show up in the network section of windows explorer like it did when connecting via softether. Mapping the drive does "work" but the application I'm using will not accept mapped drives.  Any suggestions or help would be wonderful, I can provide mroe information, or try to find it if you need it to answer my question.

Comment: Does the application not accept `\\ip.add.re.ss\sharename` either?

Comment: it won't accept \\ip.add.re.ss what would the sharename be? As far I am concerned it doens't have one

Comment: Shared folders on SMB servers always have a "share name", that's how SMB always works. It's the name you set in the "properties" window when setting up a share, it's the same name you see when you're browsing via the network section, and it's the same name you see when you access the folder via IP address.

Comment: That did work! I was able to access it thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Network discovery via IPsec VPNs**

This is normal – the discovery protocols as well the "local hostname" resolution protocols rely on multicast (newer ones) or IPv4 broadcast (NetBIOS). Some VPNs can carry non-unicast packets, others cannot, yet others deliberately refuse to.

That said, it is very rare that applications actually *require* selecting a shared folder through network discovery. If they did so, they would be unable to work on many corporate networks (as the discovery protocols do not work across different subnets either, and most corporate LANs outright disallow them).

**Alternatives**

If the program allows it, just input the actual path to the share. Even without a drive letter mapping, you can always access the fileserver via `\\ip.add.re.ss`, its individual shares as `\\ip.ad.dr\ShareName`, and of course files/folders as `\\ip.ad.dr\ShareName\path\to\file`.

(In SMB-based fileservers there is *always* a "share name", which you can see in Windows Explorer. In fact, it is easiest to just navigate to the location through Windows Explorer and copy the final path from the address bar.)